# publish the nth attribute from a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model student with a subject and grade attribute.  A student can have many subjects and grades, and what I'd like to do is be able to publish the 2nd or 3rd subject listed for a specific student.

For example, the user searches for a student, then clicks on the student, which brings them to a separate page listing information about that particular student (ie, student id:1).  Is there code I can add to the view to list the nth item from the subject and grade attributes?

I looked online here and found similar questions, but those solutions related to the model, not the attributes.  For example, one solution recommended using the limit method in the controller and another recommended using the following code:

```
 <% firm.state_of_business.split(',').each_with_index do |state, index| %>
        <td> <b>State <%= index + 1 %></b> <%= state %>
```

This seems to work well, when you don't have a specific model selected.  When you select a particular model(ie, student id:1), this doesn't seem to work.  At least not for me.  Right now my code below is showing the first item.  How might I get it to list subject 1 & grade 1, subject 2 & grade 2, subject 3 & grade 3, etc.. See sample code below. Please note, that I tried other solutions on here, but couldn't get them to work, which made me think that my problem might be different than the ones previously presented.  Thanks for your help.

**View Code**

```
<h2>Students</h2>

    <p> Student:
   <%= @student.name %>
</p>

<table>
  <tr>
     <th> Subject </th>
     <th> Grade </th>

</tr>
    <tr>
         <td><%= @student.subject %> </td>
         <td><%= @student.grade %> </td>
    <tr>
    </table>
```

**Controller Show Method**

```
  def show
     @user = current_user 
     @student = Student.find(params[:id])
  end
```

**Desired Output**

```
Student: Matt Jones

Subject  Grade
Math      95
History   90
English   91
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this code:

```
  <%= @student.grade.split(',')[0] %>
```

The [0] will publish the first item in the array.  [1] will publish the 2nd item, etc.  That should work.

Comment: thanks richiepop! that solution works perfectly.  It's actually very similar to what I found on here, but a little different.  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can just create another model called `Subject` and add `has_many :subjects` in `class Student`.

In `class Subject`, you can add this line `belongs_to :student`.

And then you can do this something like this:

```
<% @student.subjects.each do |subject| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= subject.name %> </td>
    <td><%= subject.grade %> </td>
  <tr>
<% end %>
```

Just to make it clear, `Subject` model contains attribute `name` and `grade` in above example.

Comment: thanks for your response, adrian.  I did give this solution some thought, but given the fact that I have many attributes, thought I'd try and find a way to publish the nth item without having to create a separate model.  Hoping there is another way.  Thank you, though.